"Интимный" всегда сопряжен с сексуальным или глубоко личным контекстом?
Можно ли назвать интимной встречу десятка лиц, не имеющих телесного контакта или симпатий личностного характера, но объединенных одной целью и либо не желающих распространения сведений о встрече, либо не желающих раскрывать ее суть действительно?

В Толковом словаре живого великорусского языка, В. И. Даль приводит такие значения слова
ИНТИМНЫЙ лат.: близкий, короткий, тесный, задушевный, сердечный, искренний; | тайный, таимный, негласный, межусобный, скрытный; | особнячный, особняковый.
Непомук Анастасьевич любил хорошо поесть и хорошо выпить в хорошей, интимной компании, а так как теперь собралась у него компания самая хорошая и самая интимная, и так как при этом все обретались в самом счастливом, в самом праздничном настроении духа, то Непомук достаточно успел уже ... и теперь готовился оказать еще более подобающую честь огромному ростбифу, который будет запит великолепным английским элем. [В. В. Крестовский. Панургово стадо (Ч. 1-2) (1869)]
Но в процессе этом, тяжком и многотрудном, опять постепенно истратилась интимная связь между монархом и народом. [М. О. Меньшиков. Ценз помазания (1913)]
Интимная дружба между этими двумя городами является залогом дружбы двух великих наций — России и Франции». [В. Ф. Джунковский. Воспоминания. Глава 8. 1912 год (1912)]
Поэтому во всем зале — между ними и публикой самая интимная связь. [К. И. Чуковский. Дневник 1922-1935 (1926)]
Все последующие дни до царской свадьбы (8-го мая) прошли в официальных приемах и частных пирах во дворце, в которых ярко выступала интимная близость Самозванца к его приезжим гостям. [С. Ф. Платонов. Москва и Запад в 16-17 веках (1925)]
Со временем, значение этого слова заметно изменилось. Согласно https://ushakov.slovaronline.com/21400-INTIMNYIY  ИНТИМНЫЙ ... (латин. intimus):

Относящийся к области глубоко личного, сокровенного; задушевный, близкий. Интимный разговор. Интимный друг. Вопросы о смысле бытия, о смерти, о любви - вопросы строго личные, интимные, вопросы только для меня. Максим Горький.
Не подлежащий разглашению среди других, обычно скрываемый от других. Интимные подробности туалета.
Половой (об отношениях между мужчиной и женщиной; эвф.). Они находятся в интимной связи.

Учитывая ассоциации, вызываемые значением «3», вряд ли сегодня будет уместным назвать «интимной», встречу группы лиц «не желающих распространения сведений о ней, либо не желающих раскрывать ее сути». Для такой встречи подойдут другие определения: тайная / конспиративная / секретная / конфиденциальная / закрытая / кулуарная / закулисная / нелегальная / подпольная и возможно - междусобойчик.

хм. а если изменить "уместно" на "непротиворечиво ли общему значению"? или в настоящем времени у слова понимание однозначно?

В настоящее время понимание слова «интимный» НЕоднозначно. В словаре приведены ТРИ значения.
«Общее значение» могут иметь два (или более) разных слова. Не могу понять смысл выражения «общее значение», если рассматривается только одно слово – «интимный».

Хм. Я и себя, и всех вокруг запутал. Проще говоря при употреблении какого-либо слова в речи достаточно ссылаться на словарные нормы даже если некоторые из них (в нашем случае - "сокровенный" и "не подлежащий разглашению") в настоящее время практически не используются?

Слово «сокровенный» хоронить рановато...
Сокровенное (сериал, 1 сезон, год производства 2019) https://www.kinopoisk.ru/series/1263298/?utm_referrer=www.google.com
«Вы проводите очень много времени на работе, не только работаете вместе, но и беседуете на сокровенные темы. [Зачем «Тинькофф банку» образовательная лицензия // Ведомости, 2019.03.13]

Перечень информации не подлежащей разглашению, каждая организация вправе установить самостоятельно, при этом необходимо учитывать перечень сведений, которые не могут составлять коммерческую тайну (ст.5 98-ФЗ “О коммерческой тайне”)

На носителе содержался не подлежащий разглашению список лиц, в который, в частности, входили сотрудники спецслужб. [Подозреваемый в шпионаже американец охотился за списком сотрудников спецслужб // lenta.ru, 03.01.2019]
